How to set windows positions and z-index in Rust Slint project?
I'm trying to work with Rust Slint GUI project.
But I don't know how to set windows level always top than other windows.(like z-index: 10000)
Also If run it, should displayed right side of the computer screen,(like position: absolute; right: 0;) height should computer's height(like height: 100%)
Please help me. I did some research but couldn't find it.
I hope setting windows position and z-position property.

Each component has a "z" property.  From the documentation:

z (in float): Allows to specify a different order to stack the items with its siblings. The value must be a compile time constant. (default value: 0)

